# Cookies setted but unable to maintain session using it

Tags: php, session, cookies

I setted cookies and browser shows it.But i am unable to maintain session using cookies.

```
 <?php
session_start();
include('conn.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_name'],$_SESSION['admin_id']) ||    
!isset($_COOKIE['admin_name']))
{
echo "<script>alert('Please Login To Get Access');
    window.location='login.php';</script>";
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['admin_name']))
{
$user1=$_COOKIE['admin_name']; 
session_start();
$user=$_SESSION[$user1]; 

}   
?>
```

Comment: Only use session_start() once!

Comment: Session & Cookie are 2 different things. Can you elaborate your question? And yes, your codes allow `session_start()` to be called twice, which will raise errors.

Comment: i tried but not works :(

Comment: i removed second session_start() and i can see in firefox that my cookie is setted with value but i cannot maintain session using cookie.